# including ui-router.js in HTML not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angularjs and I'm using ui-router for this but it throws Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error in console.

What is the mistake?
I've included the script as well.

```js
var app = angular.module("SearchAPP", ['ngRoute', 'bw.paging', 'ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    var helloState = {
      name: 'tab1',
      url: '/tab1/',
      template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
    }

    var aboutState = {
      name: 'tab2',
      url: '/tab2',
      template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
    }

    $stateProvider.state(helloState);
    $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
  }
]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <a ui-sref="hello">Hello</a>
  <a ui-sref="about">About</a>

  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-ui-router@0.3.1/release/angular-ui-router.js">
 
 </html>
```

Comment: Where are you calling you first snippet there? Is it after the script tags that load all your dependencies?

Comment: I do not see a closing `</script>` tag for ui-router.

Comment: @agmcleod I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @KrzysztofKaszkowiak thanks a lot. Messed up ...

Comment: In your post there, i don't see where you're actually calling the `var app = angular.module("SearchAPP", ['ngRoute', 'bw.paging', 'ui.router']);` in your html file